# How to insert record only if not exist based on primary key? (comparing with query itself instead of table)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-backups, mysql-backup

A migration of a database has just been performed, and due to some accident of character encoding, some records are not input and I don't know which records are missing. I have a full SQL dump of the previous database, but the previous database is down.

I don't have the right to create a new table. As the system is in use already, it is impossible to clear the table and dump again. As the dump of the previous table looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `surveys` (`id`, `column2`, `column3`, ...., `columnN`) VALUES
    (1, 'value2', 'value3', ...., 'valueN'), 
    (2, 'value2b', 'value3b', ..., 'valueNb'),
    .................
    (x, 'value2x', 'value3x', ..., 'valueNx')
```

If one row has primary key (id in this case) duplicated, the whole chunk is not updated. Is there a way to add a checking so that only the missing rows are added into the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) ?

```
INSERT INTO `surveys` (`id`, `column2`, `column3`, ...., `columnN`) VALUES
    (1, 'value2', 'value3', ...., 'valueN'), 
    (2, 'value2b', 'value3b', ..., 'valueNb'),
    .................
    (x, 'value2x', 'value3x', ..., 'valueNx')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id`=`id`
```

Comment: What if I don't want update but ignore on duplicate key?

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` may miss some errors, that's why I added `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id`. If a duplicate key is found, it will just update `id` with its own value.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I just wondered what that update do. I have tried an it works well.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `ignore` keyword to the [insert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) statement:

```
insert ignore into ...
```

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the
>   INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that
>   duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table
>   causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With
>   IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors
>   generate warnings instead.

The other alternative is to restore the data to a different table and the use [insert ... select ...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) with a left join and is null in the where clause to insert only the non-existing data to the main table.

Comment: Do I have a choice to ignore the error of duplication only? I still want it to stop in case there are other types of error.

Comment: Then use the 2nd approach I described in my answer.

Comment: Well, too bad I don't have the permission to create another table, but thanks for your advice. Will be useful if I have the permission next time.